# How to Set Aws Amazon Server Time? Can't find /etc/sysconfig/clock file

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to change my time to singapore time.

I read in there documentation that i have t  edit the clock file inside:
/etc/sysconfig/

Documenation:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html

I did `cd /etc/sysconfig` and i get `No Such File Directory`

I also did `ls /etc/` there really isn't any sysconfig folder. 
I did find a `timezone` File so i tried

```
sudo nano /etc/timezone
```

The file only says ETC/UTC

How do i change the timezone??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the /etc/sysconfig/clock file isn't there, go ahead and create it. Add the two relevant lines that the documentation refers to, create the necessary symlink and then restart the server.

```
ZONE="Asia/Singapore"
UTC=false
```

Comment: Just had to run step # 3 and #4 from the documentation after all..
and my timezone has changed.

now i am confused what the purpoe of step #2 is if i could just do step 3 and 4.

Comment: On EC2 instances AWS documentation recommends to leave param as "UTC=true", as hardware clock uses UTC time.

Comment: If `/etc/sysconfig/clock` is not present, then it is likely that there's another mechanism in place to manage timezones and you should probably find out what it is. (On newer Ubuntu and RHEL/CentOS this is `timedatectl`.) And unless you specifically need to set the hardware clock to local time, it should be left in UTC.

Answer (score 15):

If you cannot find `/etc/sysconfig/clock`, the it is probably the case that you are on a disto that doesn't use it. For at least Ubuntu 15-17 and RHEL/CentOS 7, you can use the `timedatectl` utility.

#### Show current settings

```
timedatectl
```

#### List available timezones

```
timedatectl list-timezones
```

#### Set timezone

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone <timezone>
```

This will take care of altering the `/etc/localtime` symlink.

References: [RHEL Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/chap-Configuring_the_Date_and_Time.html), [Ubuntu timedatectl(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/timedatectl.1.html)

Answer (score 7):

Did not have to to step 2 of the documentation. 
Just had to run these commands.

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles /etc/localtime
sudo reboot
```